# Replace specific characters within SQL query

Tags: sql

I'm struggling with some special characters that work fine with my SQL query, however will create problems in a secondary system (Excel), so I would like to replace them already during the query if possible.

```
TRANSACTIONS
   ID           DESC

    1           14ft
    2           15/16ft
    3           17ft
```

This is just a dummy example, but "/" represents one of the characters I need to remove, but there are a few different. Although it should technically work, I can't use:

```
select ID, case when DESC = '15/16ft' then '15_16ft' else DESC from TRANSACTIONS
```

I can't keep track on all the strings, so I should approach based on character. I'd prefer converting them to another char or removing them altogether.

Unfortunately not sure on the exact db engine, although good chance it's an IBM based product, but most "generic" SQL queries tend to run fine. And just to emphazise that I'm looking to convert data within the SQL query, not update the database records. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try if `replace(desc, '/', '_')` works.

Comment: Thanks, it worked fine, just had to nest several replace-commands